# Is the Windows 10/11 SDK required for C++ development in VS?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi

I am planning to develop a C++ application in Visual Studio 2022.

However, when I select the "Development with C++" option while installing, one of the selected components was Windows 11 SDK.
Also, I need to reduce installation space for I have ~90GB of space, and I am developing over many platforms (C#, Java, HTML, OpenRA, Yuri's Revenge).

None of the sources I have read state whether this is optional.
They only mention that the Windows SDK includes libraries for C++ applications to run.
Previously while installing, the installer froze on the SDK, so I would prefer to skip it if possible.

Comment: What kind of C++ application? Windows SDK is required only for accessing Windows-specific features. Like GUI. Windows SDK is like 1-2GB big afaik.

Comment: Its' optional since you can remove it, but you may have issues if your code has some adherence to the Windows platform (Universal Windows Platform tools, Xamarin, Windows App SDK, etc.). If you stick to the stdlib headers for example, it works fine w/o the Windows SDK. Anyway, you can try and add it again later on if you see it's needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, It depends on what kind of project you are developing.

The Windows SDK provides access to all of the APIs and development features exposed by the Windows OS. The Windows SDK is required for building Windows apps as well as other types of components (such as services and drivers).

The Windows App SDK provides a unified set of APIs and tools that are decoupled from the OS and released to developers via NuGet packages. If you develop standard C++ Program. You could also code/get it manually as needed, but it's more convenient to use the windows SDK.

Refer to the links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/system-requirements

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-sdk/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/how-to-use-the-windows-10-sdk-in-a-windows-desktop-application?view=msvc-170

Comment: When installing the Desktop development with C++ on Windows 10 machine, the "Windows 11 SDK" is preselected, while "Windows 10 SDK" is not. I wonder what that means. Will I not be able to run the apps that I write on this Windows 10 machine unless I tick the "Windows 10 SDK" as well?